# Merging Multdimensional Array with similiar Key PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I've been struggling with this issue for the past couple of days now. I've looked around StackOverflow but have only encountered topics where the solution relies on all the keys in the multidimensional array are the same.

My issue is merging a multidimensional array based on a similar key and value.

Current Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-17 [c] => 1 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-17 [b] => 1 
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [y] => 2015-10-17 [d] => 1 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-17 [a] => 6 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-18 [e] => 2 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-18 [c] => 1 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-18 [b] => 1 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-20 [c] => 1 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-20 [b] => 2 
    ) 
)
```

Desired Output:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-17 [c] => 1 [b] => 1 [d] => 1 [a] => 6 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-18 [e] => 2 [c] => 1 [b] => 1 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [y] => 2015-10-20 [c] => 1 [b] => 2 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: What do the original arrays look like? We can't tell you how to convert them if we don't have any idea what they look like.

Comment: The original array is posted above under Current Output:
, and the desired output is below? Sorry if I messed something upp?

Comment: You didn't mess anything up. But I am struggling to see exactly how the first changed into the second there. All algorithms require some pattern of automation and I do not see one there. It looks as though it was arbitrarily, manually edited. Can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Never mind. I just noticed that they were grouped by dates. Should not be too hard. I will work on it tomorrow if no one has answered by then.

Answer (score 1):

Create a result array with the date as the key.  If it exists merge it.  Then use `array_values()` to re-index the result:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    if(isset($result[$value['y']])) {
        $result[$value['y']] = array_merge($result[$value['y']], $value);
    } else {
        $result[$value['y']] = $value;
    }
}
$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Lifesaver mate. (Y)
Thanks for the explanation as well.